# Can't read property of undefined mongoose/mongo

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, backend

**You can check this link for full code [here](https://github.com/rippedguy/web_dev/tree/master)**

```
> function seedDB () {
Campgrounds.remove({},function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }    
    else {
        console.log("Removed All Camping Sites!");
        data.forEach(function(seed){
            Campgrounds.create(seed,function(err){
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("A Campground Has Been Successfully Added!");
                    Comments.create ({
                        title:"Really Great  Place, Definately worth it.",
                        author:"Chris"
                    },function(err,comment){
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            Campgrounds.comments.push(comment);
                            Campgrounds.save();
                            console.log("comment added");
                        }
                    });
                }
                
            });
        });
    }
});
```

}

**Everything is Working fine until Campgrounds.comments.push(...) as it throws an error "Can't read the push of undefined something like that. All modules and files are included in my github."**

Comment: Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Code is confusing with the call backs. Recommend using function declarations and passing the function variables. Might clean up code. Variable comment is undefined because the  Comments.create function isn't passing undefined to into the callback function.

Comment: can you verify that Campgrounds.comments is an array property type?

Comment: line 47-48 in seed.js `Campgrounds` is a *model* not a **document**, you need to get the document when you call `Campgrounds.create()` and use `.comments.push()` and `.save()` on that **document**

Comment: @KarlL Idk I'm new to this stuff, You can check that out in my GitHub repo, there is a file called Campgrounds.js that contains Campgrounds Schema.

Comment: @thammada.ts Ohh but I have no clue on retrieving document :(

Comment: @rippedguy it's the same way how you retrieved `comment` after you created it